# XSLT 2.0: Rounding result of calculation to two decimals

Tags: xslt, rounding, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0, rounding-error

I am using xslt 2.0 and Saxon 9.6, and need to multiply a price amount and quantity, and then round the result to two decimals.I do not want banker's rounding, I want to round so .495 = 0.50 and .494 = .49.  I have tried read several articles and posts regarding this issue, but I cannot find the solution. I see several places that rounding with xslt 1.0 is problematic because of the floating point issue, and a lot of mentions that the xslt 2.0 and the xs:decimal should do the trick, but I cannot seem to find a "waterproof" solution.

I have an xml file (Invoice) with 4 different InvoiceLines containing a price and a quantity element:

```
<Invoice>
<ID>12345</ID>
<IssueDate>2012-11-21</IssueDate>

<Supplier>
    <Party>
        <ID>977187761</ID>
    </Party>
</Supplier>
<Customer>
    <Party>
        <ID schemeID="NO:ORGNR">810305282</ID>
    </Party>
</Customer>
<Delivery>
    <DeliveryDate>2012-11-21</DeliveryDate>
</Delivery>
<TaxTotal>
    <TaxAmount currencyID="NOK">128.89</TaxAmount>
</TaxTotal>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Quantity unitCode="EA">19</Quantity>
    <LineAmount currencyID="NOK">130.26</LineAmount>
    <Item>
        <Name>TestItem</Name>
    </Item>
    <Price currencyID="NOK">8.569736842105263</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Quantity unitCode="NAR">1.00</Quantity>
    <LineAmount currencyID="NOK">128.2</LineAmount>
    <Item>
        <Name>Vare A</Name>
    </Item>
    <Price currencyID="NOK">128.195</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Quantity unitCode="NAR">1.00</Quantity>
    <LineAmount currencyID="NOK">128.7</LineAmount>
    <Item>
        <Name>Vare B</Name>
    </Item>
    <Price currencyID="NOK">128.695</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
<InvoiceLine>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Quantity unitCode="NAR">1.00</Quantity>
    <LineAmount currencyID="NOK">128.4</LineAmount>
    <Item>
        <Name>Vare C</Name>
    </Item>
    <Price currencyID="NOK">128.395</Price>
</InvoiceLine>
```

I have run the following xslt on the xml:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="//InvoiceLine">
                <tr>

                    <td>Line: <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>  </td>

                    <td>Price: <xsl:value-of select="Price"/></td>

                    <td>Quantity: <xsl:value-of select="Quantity"/></td>

                    <td>LineAmount: <xsl:value-of select="LineAmount"/></td>

                    <td>P*Q: <xsl:value-of select="Price * Quantity"/></td>

                    <td>Round(p*q*100)div 100: <xsl:value-of select="round((Price * Quantity * 100)) div 100" /></td>

                    <td>xs:decimal(p*q): <xsl:value-of select="xs:decimal(Price * Quantity)" /></td>

                    <td>round((p*q)*10*10) div 100: <xsl:value-of select="round((Price * Quantity) * 10 * 10) div 100"/></td>


                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

And this is the result:

```
<html xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:op="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xquery-operators" xmlns:schold="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron" xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ubl="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
   <body>
  <tr>
     <td>Line: 1</td>
     <td>Price: 8.569736842105263</td>
     <td>Quantity: 19</td>
     <td>LineAmount: 130.26</td>
     <td>P*Q: 162.825</td>
     <td>Round(p*q*100)div 100: 162.82</td>
     <td>xs:decimal(p*q): 162.82499999999998863131622783839702606201171875</td>
     <td>round((p*q)*10*10) div 100: 162.83</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Line: 2</td>
     <td>Price: 128.195</td>
     <td>Quantity: 1.00</td>
     <td>LineAmount: 128.2</td>
     <td>P*Q: 128.195</td>
     <td>Round(p*q*100)div 100: 128.2</td>
     <td>xs:decimal(p*q): 128.19499999999999317878973670303821563720703125</td>
     <td>round((p*q)*10*10) div 100: 128.19</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Line: 3</td>
     <td>Price: 128.695</td>
     <td>Quantity: 1.00</td>
     <td>LineAmount: 128.7</td>
     <td>P*Q: 128.695</td>
     <td>Round(p*q*100)div 100: 128.7</td>
     <td>xs:decimal(p*q): 128.69499999999999317878973670303821563720703125</td>
     <td>round((p*q)*10*10) div 100: 128.69</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Line: 4</td>
     <td>Price: 128.395</td>
     <td>Quantity: 1.00</td>
     <td>LineAmount: 128.4</td>
     <td>P*Q: 128.395</td>
     <td>Round(p*q*100)div 100: 128.4</td>
     <td>xs:decimal(p*q): 128.395000000000010231815394945442676544189453125</td>
     <td>round((p*q)*10*10) div 100: 128.4</td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see, I get different results of the different types of calculations/rounding. For line 1 I get the exptected result in the last calculation, but for line 2 and 3, this calculation does not give me the exptected result.

I would be very greatful for any tips on how to solve this.

Comment: Can you post the input please.

Comment: I just edited my question with the input xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Price * Quantity, '0.00')"/>
```

---

Note also that I get the same - expected - results with all of these:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(Price * Quantity * 100) div 100" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(xs:decimal(Price) * xs:decimal(Quantity) * 100) div 100" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:value-of select="round(xs:decimal(Price) * xs:decimal(Quantity) * 10 * 10) div 100"/>
```

---

### Correction:

If you don't want "banker's rounding", then you cannot use the `format-number()` function, since it does the same rounding as `round-half-to-even()` does - see point #5 here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#formatting-the-number

However, all the other methods do the expected rounding to the nearest integer.

Comment: Do you get the expected result for all 4 lines with all of these variants? May I ask which xslt proc. you are using? All of these suggestions gives me the result of 162.82 and not 162.83 as I expect on line 1.

Comment: "*not 162.83 as exptected.*" That's an unwarranted expectation, because `19 * 8.569736842105263` is actually `162.824999999999997` - see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19+*+8.569736842105263)

Comment: Hmmm... using a normal, old-fashioned calculator I get 162.825. Also, if you look at the result of `<xsl:value-of select="Price * Quantity"/>` it is 162.825 and should be rounded to 162.83. Or??

Comment: I took the time to do the really old-fashioned, analogue calculation using pen and paper, and you are correct @michael.hor257k, the result is `162.82499999999997`.   Sorry for not checking this before posting!

Answer (score 5):

I assume you aren't using schema-awareness, which means that the values such as Price and Quantity are untypedAtomic. If you use an untypedAtomic value as input to an arithmetic operator, it is treated as double-precision floating point. So the first thing you should do is cast explicitly to xs:decimal: your code `xs:decimal(Price * Quantity)` does the multiplication using double arithmetic, and casts the result to a decimal, whereas `xs:decimal(Price) * xs:decimal(Quantity)` will use decimal arithmetic.

If you make sure that the untyped values are all converted to decimal before you do any arithmetic, then rounding and formatting of the result should work "as expected".

Comment: But why then does the <xsl:value-of select="round(xs:decimal(Price) * xs:decimal(Quantity) * 100) div 100" /> give me the wrong result on line 1? It returns 162.82, should be 162.83. Same for <xsl:value-of select="round(xs:decimal(Price) * xs:decimal(Quantity) * 10 * 10) div 100"/>

Comment: Please see my comment on the post above, I have been trusting the calculator too much, the result should actually be 162.82. My mistake!